# Mapping db view without Id to class model in NHibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, automapping

In my application, I use NHibernate ORM and Automapper to mapping entities to class model. As:
[fluent-nhibernate/wiki/Auto-mapping](https://github.com/jagregory/fluent-nhibernate/wiki/Auto-mapping)

For tables its working.

Problem is when a try mapping db view without Id field, like:

```
public class VTest
{

    [NotNull]
    public virtual AAATab AAA { get; set; }
    [NotNull]
    public virtual BBBTab BBB { get; set; }
```

}

I create composite key :

```
public void Override(AutoMapping<VTest> mapping)
    {
        mapping.IgnoreProperty(x => x.Id);
        mapping.CompositeId()
                .KeyProperty(x => x.AAA.Id)
               .KeyProperty(x => x.BBB.Id);
    }
```

but it not working. A get error, becouse in the db query have select id :

> [GenericADOException: could not execute query [ SELECT this_.Id as
>   Id7_0_, this_.AAAId as AAAId7_0_, this_.BBBId as
>   BBB_7_0_ FROM [VTest] this_ ]

Its possible use automapper for this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find solutions. In compositeKey must use phisical exist property in db view, so i create new properties:

```
public virtual int AAAId {get;set;}
public virtual int BBBId {get;set;}
```

And i create:

```
    mapping.IgnoreProperty(x => x.Id);
    mapping.CompositeId()
           .KeyProperty(x => x.AAAId)
           .KeyProperty(x => x.BBBId);
```

This automapping for view or table without Id works. (To model dbview or table, you need add override function Equals() and GetHashCode() )